# setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler() when doing executeMediaAsInputStream()

Tags: google-api-java-client

I'm adding exponential backoff to handle unsuccessful GCS requests. I'm essentially replacing `AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute()` with building the `HttpRequest`, setting the unsuccessful response handler, and then calling `execute()` on the `HttpRequest` instead. However, I've now run into the following situation trying to translate `executeMediaAsInputStream()`:

```
Storage.Objects.Get get = this.storage.objects().get(bucket, key);
//InputStream is = get.executeMediaAsInputStream(); REPLACING THIS...
HttpRequest r = get.buildHttpRequest();
r.setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(new HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(new ExponentialBackOff()));
//...WITH WHAT?
```

`r.execute().getContent()` returns me an `InputStream` but I suspect that loses me the "media" information. Am I on the right track or should I be approaching things differently?